# Is there a way to add automatic signatures to all outgoing e-mail in exchange '03?

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook

There's some legal that the boss would like added to all outgoing e-mail. Without creating a signature and relying on users to remember to add it to their e-mail, can all outgoing e-mails have a signature appended to their e-mail?

Comment: Sigh...don't you just love it when the boss reads a high tech legal article in his "how to be the boss" magazine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it.

You can push out a script via group policy to generate a signature on the client machine and then force its use - assuming you are using outlook. There are some downfalls to this method

- Signature will be applied to ALL emails, internal and within email chains
- Technically they could just delete the signature when they are creating a new email
- This won't get applied to OWA/activesync users

There are some 3rd party solutions that will do this for you, exclaimer and codetwo exchange rules come to mind.

Exclaimer is quite involved, I've used codetwo exchange rules and find it excellent.

Advantages

- Signature gets applied by the server, so no tampering
- Can select it to only be appended to external email
- Will search for duplicates and only apply signature once per email chain
- Applies to OWA/Activesync
- Can set rules per OU (different disclaimers for different users if needed)

You can try codetwo's software for free (it'll put a link to their website at the bottom until you license it).

Failing that most SPAM filtering will have this feature depending on your requirements.

Comment: +1, exactly what I would've said. I wrote a vbscript about a year ago which created an Outlook signature upon logon. It pulled all its info from AD which was nice. Its basically a poor man's "Exclaimer", but it works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using an event sink like described in this kb [arcticle](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;317680&x=6&y=16) and registered like explained in this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526620(EXCHG.10).aspx).
Hope this helps.